# What is an English word for when a problem requires a solution to solve and reach that same solution?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to log into a website, but i don't have the Username and Password. When I contact support they answered me by giving a link to view their comment on their secure tech support page. To view the page it requires me to log in with the credentials i asked for in the first place. What is the English word for this?

Comment: *Catch-22* springs to mind.

Answer (score 1):

That's a classic case of a ***Catch-22*** as given first as a comment by @StoneyB.  This is a paradoxical rule postulated in the novel (and later film) called *Catch-22* by Joseph Heller ([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28813?redirectedFrom=catch%2022#eid9827650)).

> Catch 22 n. a supposed law or regulation containing provisions which
>   are mutually frustrating (see quot. 1961); a set of circumstances in
>   which one requirement, etc., is dependent upon another, which is in
>   turn dependent upon the first. Frequently attrib., esp. as Catch-22
>   situation.

1961   J. Heller Catch-22 v   There was only one catch, and that was Catch-22... If he flew them [more missions] he was crazy and didn't have to; but if he didn't want to he was sane and had to.